# How to run a JSR223 PreProcessor script once per loop

Tags: jmeter

I currently have a loop that executes a bunch of queries via JDBC request samplers. They should all share a random ID that changes on every loop.

I tried using the beanshell script and JSR223 PreProcessor. But the PreProcessor gets executed before every single JDBC reuqest sampler, not once per loop. I feel like there is an obvious fix to my problem that I am missing.

[image: jmeter loop]

I also tried putting the JSR223 script into an "Only Once Controller". But then the random variable I inject with `vars.put()` is not visible to the JDBC sampler. Also, as far as i understand the Only Once Controller, it would only execute on the first loop iteration. Which is not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSR223 PreProcessor obeys [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) so if you put it to be a child of i.e. `q_insert1` sampler - it will be executed only once per iteration.

[image]

I would also recommend re-considering language selection, [since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use Groovy for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)